# Polymer 1.x - cannot bind to href

Tags: polymer, href, polymer-1.0

I would like to bind URL address to href.
I tried the way recommended by polymer datasheet:

```
<a href$="{{excelURL}}" class="btn btn--call-to-action" id="downloadBtn">Download excel</a>
```

Anyway it is not working, and  element is not linked.Also without $ it is not working.  Normally other properties can be bind that way. Have you got an idea how to resolve it?

Comment: What do you mean that it's not working? The href is not set at all? It is, but when you click on the anchor what you expect doesn't happen?

Comment: I did not try this yet but you could just load the url programatically on-tap

Comment: That should've worked (as seen in [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/WzJGJX)). Do you have a repro?

Answer (score 0):

I could not bind property like above. I resolved it that way:

```
this.$.downloadBtn.href = this.apiUrl
```